# SQL - Inclusive Matches in column or across multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I don't know how to search for it.

First off, I do not want to implement full-text searching. The database contains multiple languages including Chinese and Japanese which pose a huge problem for Full-text indexes.

I have a table like the following:

Table `Comment`:

```
UserID int
CommentText nvarchar(400)
```

I want to do a search against this table and find anything matching multiple words. Normally I would just do something like

```
select * 
from Comment 
where CommentText like '%potato%' and CommentText like '%badger%'
```

But if the two words are in different rows I need to do something like

```
select 
    UserID, count(UserID ) 
from 
    Comment
where 
    CommentText like '%potato%' or CommentText like '%badger%'
group by 
    UserID 
having 
    count(UserID ) > 1
```

But then if the words are sometimes in the same row and sometimes spread across multiple rows, how do I determine if both words matched?

Cases:

1. Both words are in a single row.
2. One word is in row 1 and the other word is in row 2 for the same UserID
3. One word is in multiple rows for the same UserID (so it returns multiple matches even if it's the same word several times)

**My question is**: for multiple words, how do I conduct a wildcard search and make sure all the words match at least once for a given UserID?

Thanks in advance

I'm thinking of a CTE to grab all rows that contain matches and concat them for a given userid, but I don't know if I can find something more efficient.

Comment: Should "badger" match "badgering"? What if "bad" and "badger" are both search terms? Using wildcard matches is not the same as parsing words from a string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this would use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM Comment
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN CommentText LIKE '%java%'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN CommentText LIKE '%python%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Each of the sums in the `HAVING` clause keep track of each individual word you want to match.  Only when at least one record has a positive match, for both words, would a user turn up in the result set.

Note that if you plan to continue down this road, you should look into SQL Server's full text capabilities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search

Answer (score -1):

Just posting the question caused me to think of the answer.

```
select distinct UserID from (
    select UserID FROM Comment where CommentText like '%java%' 
    UNION 
    select UserID FROM Comment where CommentText like '%python%' 
) as a
```

Comment: wht if `select distinct UserID FROM Comment where CommentText like '%java%' or CommentText like '%python%' `

Comment: I don't think this logic is correct.  If, for example, a user matched `java` but not `python`, then you would still be including him in the result set.